# MySQL: Multiple conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, multiple-conditions

Using MySQL

What i wan't to achieve is to ONLY return products (WHERE pf.filter = 10 AND pf.filter = 15 AND pf.filter = 18) and no other products.

I thought the below query would work, but it gives me no results.
When i remove the WHERE, AND conditions there is 3 rows where pf.filter_id is 10,15,18

```
SELECT * FROM products p
LEFT JOIN filter pf ON (p.product_id = pf.product_id)
WHERE pf.filter = 10
AND pf.filter = 15
AND pf.filter = 18
GROUP BY p.product_id
```

How should this SQL Query be constructed to work?

Comment: It seems okay the way you do this, multiple AND works well usually, are you sure it is not a logic problem ? I can see that you ask filter that are equal to 15 AND filter that equal to 18, it shoudl be OR

Comment: it is a logic problem, a field cannot be more than one value at a time.

Comment: How can `filter` be 10 AND 15 AND 18?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by logic problem?

Comment: So if you're saying a product must have all 3 filter critiera then a `having` is count=3 is one way to do this.  If it can be any of the 3 then `or` or `in` would work.  I have a vehicle.  It can't be a CAR, Van and truck.  it could be a car, or van or truck.  ... or i could have a car with 4 doors, automatic, and sunroof.... must it have all 3 criteria or any of the 3?

Comment: Yes, okay...it's probably a logic problem.

I tried using WHERE pf.filter_id IN (11,15,18) and that gives me a result. but that it's a replacement for OR, and i wan't AND. Hope that wasn't to confusing :)

WHERE pf.filter_id IN (10,15,17,999) should give me no result because there is no matching filter with filter_id = 999

Comment: xQbert: Should be AND

Answer (score 1):

The value of `filter` can't be 10, 15 and 18 the same time.

You probably want the value to be 10 OR 15 OR 18:

```
SELECT * FROM products p
LEFT JOIN filter pf ON (p.product_id = pf.product_id)
WHERE pf.filter = 10
OR pf.filter = 15
OR pf.filter = 18
GROUP BY p.product_id
```

Comment: `or` (pun intended)  `in`

Comment: @xQbert, correct :) the `in` will give the same result here.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` to get the products that have all three filters.  Then join in the rest of the information:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM products p JOIN
     (SELECT pf.product_id
      FROM filter pf
      WHERE pf.filter IN (10, 15, 18)
      GROUP BY pf.product_id
      HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
     ) pf
     ON p.product_id = pf.product_id;
```

Comment: Looks promising, will try this tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the value can't be 10 and 15 and 18 at the same time, try this:

```
SELECT * FROM products p
LEFT JOIN filter pf ON (p.product_id = pf.product_id)
WHERE pf.filter = 10
OR pf.filter = 15
OR pf.filter = 18
GROUP BY p.product_id
```

or better

```
SELECT * FROM products p
LEFT JOIN filter pf ON (p.product_id = pf.product_id)
WHERE pf.filter IN (10, 15, 18)
GROUP BY p.product_id
```

Comment: Yes, that was how the query looked like from the start. The only problem is that it should be AND rather than OR.

So..

WHERE pf.filter IN (10, 15, 18, 999) should give me no results because there is no filter_id = 999

Comment: IN (10, 15, 18, 999) is equivalent to OR filter=10 OR filter=15 OR filter=18 OR filter = 999. So if you even don't have 999 it still shows rows 10, 15 and 18